# Prove that the sum of inverses of factorials is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k!}$.

I must show that the sequence $S_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence, which means:

$$\forall\epsilon\gt 0 \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } (n \gt n_0 \text{ } \land \text{ } m \gt n_0 \implies |S_m - S_n| < \epsilon) $$

This is what I've tried so far:

Assuming WLOG $m > n$

$$|S_m - S_n| = \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{k!} = \dfrac{1}{m!} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \prod\limits_{i=k+1}^m i \leq \dfrac{1}{m!} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \prod\limits_{i=k+1}^m m \leq \dfrac{1}{m!} \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m m^{m-k}$$
$$\implies |S_m - S_n| \leq \dfrac{m^m}{m!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{m^k} = \dfrac{m^{m-n}-1}{m!(m-1)}$$

But now I am stuck. I realize my attempt is probably going anywhere because of the substitution that $i \leq m$, which is a big change. Still, I decided to see if I could get somewhere, but got stuck.

I have two questions.

**1. Is it possible to continue my approach and complete the proof?**

**2. What would be a better way to handle this?**

*Note: I know this sequence converges to $e$ because this is exactly the Taylor Series for the function $e^x$ when $x = 0$, but I don't want to use that fact. I would like to proceed as the question asks, and prove that it is a Cauchy Sequence first, to only then conclude that it is convergent.*

*Note 2: I would tag this as homework-and-exercises but I couldn't find that tag, maybe I saw this tag in another SE instead of Math.SE.*

Comment: Do you know that the series $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 \ldots$ is convergent? Your series is less than that.

Comment: aka, the Comparison Theorem.

Comment: as @user2566092 suggests use $\frac{1}{k!}\leq\frac{1}{2^k}$.

Comment: Re: Note 2, the homework tag was eliminated here because as tags go, it was pretty useless.  Tags are important for searching, esp. in automated ways as when Related questions are being suggested to the Reader.

Comment: Indeed, I don't know how I missed the $\frac{1}{k!} \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$, it was an easy one. Thank you very much, I won't miss those ever again! And thanks @hardmath that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have shown this,
I base my bounds 
on the *lower* index,
not the upper.

$\begin{array}\\
|S_m - S_n| 
&= \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{k!} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{n!}{k!} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{\prod_{j=n+1}^k j} \\
&\le \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{\prod_{j=n+1}^k (n+1)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^m \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{k-n}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-n} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{k}} \\
&< \dfrac{1}{n!}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^{k}} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n!}\frac{1/(n+1)}{1-1/(n+1)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{n\cdot n!} \\
\end{array}
$

and this goes to zero
as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Excellent. I liked how instead of just showing a solution you warned me about choosing to work with the lower index. I see this will help me in many other problems. Of course I will have to adjust this proof to be formally correct within the epsilons definition, but that will be straightforward. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!}\\
&\leq 2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n \left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k}\\
&=2+1-\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{align}
$$

The series is monotonous because $\frac{1}{k!}\geq 0$ and has an upper limit the series converges.